# .htaccess sub-subdomain rewrite in Laravel

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I have a Laravel install that is using the standard `.htaccess` file, which works great for `dev.mysite.com` but on my dev server I have `foo.dev.mysite.com` and another route which is `bar.dev.mysite.com`

The routing is working fine, but the requests are not being rewritten to index.php, for example when I go to `foo.dev.mysite.com/example` I get a 404 but when I go to `foo.dev.mysite.com/index.php?example` it's working fine.

I have the following `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is the `.htaccess` being used at all? Make a syntax error in it or something that would indicate apache is trying to use the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure mode_rewrite is enabled.  I am sure you have probably done this but I want to make sure nothing is missed. Another test is to remove the `IfModule` condition and see if it fails.

Next, see what version of apache you are running since the syntax has changed between 2.2 and 2.4. The `Optons` default was changed from `All` to `FollowSymlinks` in 2.3.11. This should not be a big deal and doubt this is the culprit but could be and save you trouble in the future.

Next, try putting the rewrite condition inside of the vhost information instead of the htaccess file. This can help a little with performance as well as give you a console warn/err when restarting apache where the htaccess errors could be squelched.

```
<directory /var/www/mysite.com>
    Options -MultiViews
    AllowOverride ALL
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</directory>
```

Beyond this point I would be at a loss without some more logging or information from the server. You can also add `CustomLog` into the vhost and report all requests processed by the server.

Comment: It turned out I hadn't enabled mod_rewrite, I am an ass.

Comment: It happens to the best of us. Dasper's rule of stupid problems: The longer I stare at it by myself, the dumber it becomes. It gets exponentially dumber if once I as for help I start the sentence with "Hey, Mike, can you help me with this? I have been staring at this for 2 hours..."